# Fixed-pitch fonts in Emacs org-mode in Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, emacs, org-mode

I started using a Windows machine provided by the company, therefore I installed Emacs and moved the configuration file to the new computer.
Everything is working as expected, except the rules written to make some faces appear as fixed-pitch fonts. And that is why tables, for example, appear like this:

[image]

The .emacs file has the following lines in it, which is working well in Debian GNU/Linux and MacOS:

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-block nil :foreground nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
(set-face-attribute 'org-code nil   :inherit '(shadow fixed-pitch))
;(set-face-attribute 'org-indent nil :inherit '(org-hide fixed-pitch))
(set-face-attribute 'org-verbatim nil :inherit '(shadow fixed-pitch))
(set-face-attribute 'org-special-keyword nil :inherit '(font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch))
(set-face-attribute 'org-meta-line nil :inherit '(font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch))
(set-face-attribute 'org-checkbox nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
(set-face-attribute 'org-table nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
(set-face-attribute 'org-date nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
(set-face-attribute 'org-footnote nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
```

How can I make dates, tables, etc. to be shown as monospaced font?

Comment: Use `C-u C-x =` in various places to make sure that at each place (e.g. in a table), the face you expect is the face used (e.g. `org-table` in a table). Then examine the face with `M-x describe face`. All I can think of is that there is no monospace font available at all, but since I don't understand faces and fonts well enough, I cannot say for sure. Also when specifying a list of faces in `:inherit`, earlier faces take precedence over later faces, so you might want to put `fixed-pitch` first - but as I said, you shouldn't believe anything I say: Caveat Emptor.

Comment: Thanks, NickD! I checked faces and everything matches the expected. Also I think that there should be a monospace font available, because other non-org buffers are using monospace fonts. Regarding the order of `:inherit` faces, I would like to insist in the fact that this code is working well in Debian as well as in MacOS.

Comment: What does `(face-font 'org-table)` return?

Comment: How can I do that? `M-x` does not recognise that command.

Comment: `ESC ESC : (face-font 'org-table) RET` or go to your `*scratch*` buffer and type `(face-font 'org-table) C-j`

Comment: `"-outline-Arial-normal-normal-normal-sans-13-*-*-*-p-*-iso8859-1"`

Comment: ... which is not a fixed-pitch font afaik. Try clicking on `Options/Set default font` and select a monospaced font (probably Courier is available on Windows, but there may be others). See if that works.

Comment: Default font *is* Courier, actually. I disabled all the variable-pitch fonts configuration for org-mode and back to default monospaced fonts, because the files became unreadable. That's the best I can do for now. Thanks a lot for your help, NickD!

Comment: Try https://emacs.stackexchange.com/